# Windows Server NTFS Advanced File Permissions

Tags: file-permissions, ntfs

Here is what I would like to do:
1) Create a main folder that doesnt allow inheritance.
2) Create a template folder with subfolders.
    2.1)Set permissions so these folders cannot be deleted.
    2.2)Set permissions so these folders can be written to.
        2.2.1)Files cannot be deleted/overwritten after written to this folder.
3) Allow the template folder to be copied and renamed, but not deleted.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't allow inheritance"?

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that an administrator will be able to change the file permissions and then make any changes they like.

1. Break inheritance by unchecking "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" in Properties -> Security -> Advanced.
   [image]
2. I think you can create directories without pictures.  (You get to this screen by clicking "Add" or "Edit" at the above screen.)

   2a. "Set permissions so these folders cannot be deleted": Set an explicit deny on delete for a group that the users belong to (I used "Domain Users") by checking the deny column's "Delete."

   2b. "Set permissions so these folders can be written to": Check the allow column's "Create files / write data."

   2c. "Files cannot be deleted/overwritten after written to this folder."  Check the deny column's "Delete subfolders and files."

[image]

3. "Allow the template folder to be copied and renamed, but not deleted."  I was able to copy the template folder with the permissions intact by using an administrative command prompt and typing `xcopy Template NewName /o /x /e /h /k`.  You didn't specify which user would be required to copy the folders, so I denied it to myself and copied it.  (It failed without an elevated command prompt.)

I hope that helps.